# How to sign JWT with PKCS#8 PrivateKeyInfo

Tags: java, jwt, apple-sign-in, nimbus-jose-jwt, p8

I can't figure out how to sign JWT with PKCS#8 key. The key is similar to this one:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIGTAgEAMBNGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBHkwdwIBAQQgtbN7M/7webqa1i3k
3UiwERpWUIoRj6nebM7yRyFphVWgCgYIKoHihj0DAQehRANCAAQl6Z+2bWXLgxJC
J2It6UNYSuxios4A1A6/7/7hNs0y3Yus53q6RD1snvMU5yTBewrRALyDz/8MNADm
eN7dRD41
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The key is explained in this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54981397/1051180

I need to use the com.nimbusds library. I think it should be doable but couldn't find the way. The closest I found is this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57437626/1051180

I managed to sign it with the io.jsonwebtoken library:

```
String token = Jwts.builder().signWith(getPrivateKey(), SignatureAlgorithm.ES256).compact();

private static PrivateKey getPrivateKey() {
    PrivateKey key = null;
    try (var pemParser = new PEMParser(privateKeyReader)) {
        var keyInfo = (PrivateKeyInfo) pemParser.readObject();
        key = new JcaPEMKeyConverter().getPrivateKey(keyInfo);      
    }
    return key;
}
```

Background: I obtained the key in an .p8 file. I use it to sign JWT that is used to authenticate against Apple server during Sign In with Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I did not have an Apple-provided private key at hand I tried to generate one myself using this command:

```bash
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out key.p8
```

Here's the code that can use such PEM file to sign a token:

```java
// load PEM as String from "key.p8" resource
String p8key;
ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
try (InputStream is = cl.getResourceAsStream("key2.p8");
     InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
     BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(isr)) {
   p8key = r.lines().collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
}

// Load ECKey from the PEM
ECKey ecJWK = (ECKey) ECKey.parseFromPEMEncodedObjects(p8key);

// Create the EC signer
JWSSigner signer = new ECDSASigner(ecJWK);

// Create the JWS object with a payload
JWSObject jwsObject = new JWSObject(
        new JWSHeader.Builder(JWSAlgorithm.ES256).keyID(ecJWK.getKeyID()).build(),
        new Payload("Elliptic cure"));

// Compute the EC signature
jwsObject.sign(signer);

// Serialize the JWS to compact form
String jwtToken = jwsObject.serialize();

// print the generated token
System.out.println(jwtToken);
```

Apparently, the PKCS#8 file provided by Apple does not have a public key included in it. Hence, the above method to create `ECDSASigner` fails with `"Missing PEM-encoded public key to construct JWK"` exception. The code below loads the private key from such PEM file and creates an instance of `ECDSASigner` which can be used to sign the token.

```java
JWSSigner signer = new ECDSASigner(loadECPrivateKey("key.p8"));

private static final Provider BC = new BouncyCastleProvider();

private ECPrivateKey loadECPrivateKey(String resource) throws Exception {
  ClassLoader cl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
  try (InputStream is = cl.getResourceAsStream(resource);
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
       BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(isr)) {

    // strip header and footer, decode from base64, then load the key
    String text = r.lines()
        .filter(s -> s.length() > 0 && !s.startsWith("---"))
        .collect(Collectors.joining());
    byte[] bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(text);

    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(bytes);
    KeyFactory factory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC", BC);
    return (ECPrivateKey)factory.generatePrivate(spec);
  }
}
```

Comment: The call to parseFromPEMEncodedObjects() throws "Exception com.nimbusds.jose.JOSEException: Missing PEM-encoded public key to construct JWK". As far as I know, Apple doesn't provide the public key.

Comment: Got it. Since I didn't have an Apple-provided key I didn't hit this problem with the self-generated key. I was able to find an example of a PKCS#8 file provided by Apple and reproduce the problem. I corrected my answer. Please see if it works for you.